# is there a way to insert data in tableview at particular row and column in javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I am having tableview with 5 rows and 3 columns. i want fill data at 1st row and 1st column.is there a way to add data.kindly show me sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below. Get the list of items from the table and update the required item in the list. Sample is below.

```
public class FxTablePagination extends Application {

    TableView<Person> table = null;

    final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("1", "Joe", "Pesci"), new Person("2", "Audrey",
                    "Hepburn"), new Person("3", "Gregory", "Peck"), new Person(
                    "4", "Cary", "Grant"), new Person("5", "De", "Niro"),
            new Person("6", "Katharine", "Hepburn"), new Person("7", "Jack",
                    "Nicholson"), new Person("8", "Morgan", "Freeman"),
            new Person("9", "Elizabeth", "Taylor"), new Person("10",
                    "Marcello", "Mastroianni"), new Person("11", "Innokenty",
                    "Smoktunovsky"), new Person("12", "Sophia", "Loren"),
            new Person("13", "Alexander", "Kalyagin"), new Person("14",
                    "Peter", "OToole"), new Person("15", "Gene", "Wilder"),
            new Person("16", "Evgeny", "Evstegneev"), new Person("17",
                    "Michael", "Caine"), new Person("18", "Jean-Paul",
                    "Belmondo"), new Person("19", " Julia", "Roberts"),
            new Person("20", "James", "Stewart"), new Person("21", "Sandra",
                    "Bullock"), new Person("22", "Paul", "Newman"), new Person(
                    "23", "Oleg", "Tabakov"), new Person("24", "Mary",
                    "Steenburgen"), new Person("25", "Jackie", "Chan"),
            new Person("26", "Rodney", "Dangerfield"), new Person("27",
                    "Betty", "White"), new Person("28", "Eddie", "Murphy"),
            new Person("29", "Amitabh", "Bachchan"), new Person("30", "Nicole",
                    "Kidman"), new Person("31", "Adriano", "Celentano"),
            new Person("32", "Rhonda", " Fleming's"), new Person("32",
                    "Humphrey", "Bogart"));
    private Pagination pagination;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    public int itemsPerPage() {
        return 1;
    }

    public int rowsPerPage() {
        return 5;
    }

    public VBox createPage(int pageIndex) {
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int displace = data.size() % rowsPerPage();
        if (displace > 0) {
            lastIndex = data.size() / rowsPerPage();
        } else {
            lastIndex = data.size() / rowsPerPage() - 1;

        }

        VBox box = new VBox(5);
        int page = pageIndex * itemsPerPage();

        for (int i = page; i < page + itemsPerPage(); i++) {
            table = new TableView<Person>();
            TableColumn numCol = new TableColumn("ID");
            numCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                    "num"));

            numCol.setMinWidth(20);

            TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
            firstNameCol
                    .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                            "firstName"));

            firstNameCol.setMinWidth(160);

            TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
            lastNameCol
                    .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                            "lastName"));

            lastNameCol.setMinWidth(160);

            table.getColumns().addAll(numCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
            if (lastIndex == pageIndex) {
                table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(
                        pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage()
                                + displace)));
            } else {
                table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(
                        pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage()
                                + rowsPerPage())));
            }

            box.getChildren().add(table);
        }
        return box;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

        pagination = new Pagination((data.size() / rowsPerPage() + 1), 0);
        // pagination = new Pagination(20 , 0);
        pagination.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
        pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
            @Override
            public Node call(Integer pageIndex) {
                if (pageIndex > data.size() / rowsPerPage() + 1) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return createPage(pageIndex);
                }
            }
        });

        Button modifyBtn = new Button("Modify");

        **// To update a column content or row content in the table view**
        modifyBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    ObservableList<Person> columns = table.getItems();
                    Person item = columns.get(0);
                    item.setFirstName("Name modified");
                    columns.add(0, item);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(pagination, 30.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        anchor.getChildren().addAll(pagination, modifyBtn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchor, 400, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Table pager");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty num;
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String id, String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.num = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getNum() {
            return num.get();
        }

        public void setNum(String id) {
            num.set(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am able to add data using observerable list. But my problem is how to change particular cell through event.

Comment: @pavankumar U mean, you need a editable table cell? or on what event you need to change the cell content?

Comment: First i will add empty data to tableview. After adding i will have a row with null data in each column. Here, On clicking button i want to change column 0th null data to some text i.e( here i want "abc" in 0th column ).